# FATAL ERROR while compiling Project using Maven 2

Tags: maven-2

I am new to Maven and starting moving my project to maven. I have created the following POM.
when i issue install command, it gives me FATAL ERROR.

I am using maven 2.2.1 version and JDK 1.5.

My POM is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <prerequisites>
        <maven>2.2.1</maven>
    </prerequisites>
    <groupId>my.project.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.artifact</artifactId>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6.SEC01</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Rather than just saying FATAL ERROR, please post the actual error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a mandatory tag from your project address structure **groupId:artifactId:version**

Put the following tag after ... with some version info (i.e. 1.x.x) and try.

```
<version>1.0.0</version>
```

Reference : http://maven.apache.org/pom.html